# How to set user name to UITextField from FBSDKGraphRequest result

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I am using Xcode 10, Swift 5 and I am trying to set a UITextField to just the user name I retrieved from Facebook. I have successfully retrieved the ID, Email, and Name in result but when I sent result to the text field is includes all three fields. I just want the name.

```
func getUserProfile() {
    let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name"], tokenString: accessToken?.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET")
    req?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error : Error!) -> Void in
        if(error == nil)
        {
            print("\(String(describing: result))")
            self.FBUserName.text = "name \(String(describing: result))"
        }
        else
        {
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast result to `[String : Any]`, like so

```
if error != nil {
    print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
} else if let result = result as? [String : Any] {
    self.FBUserName.text = result["name"] as! String
}
```

Here is my working request

```
let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email,name"])
graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { [weak self] (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else if let result = result as? [String : Any], let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.txtName.text = (result["name"] as! String)
        strongSelf.txtEmail.text = (result["email"] as! String)
    }
})
```

Comment: i get an error: Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'valueForKey'